# How to get a Label with AutoSize to update its Position while anchored to the Right?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple `System.Windows.Forms.Label` in a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.
I want to dynamically resize the label to fit text loaded runtime, while keeping it Anchored to the right and bottom of its parent form.

According to the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/autosize-property-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

- It is “always true” that the Location Property remains constant (i.e., that the top left position of the Control will never change).
- It is “always true” that the Anchor property is respected when AutoSize is true (i.e., that the Location Property—the top-left corner—will be modified so that the Anchored Sides maintain their initial distance from the edges of their parent controls).

From my reading of this, I would expect that the second truth overrides the first when `Anchor` is anything but `AnchorStyles.None`.
However, this doesn't seem to bear out in practice.

Consider the following:

```
    // From ExampleForm.Designer.cs
    this.label = new System.Drawing.Label();
    this.label.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    this.label.AutoSize = true;
    this.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, 400);
    this.label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 20);
    this.label.Text = "[Populated at Runtime]";
    this.label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    // ...
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label);
    // ...


    // Sometime after Form Initialization, this is called
    void PopulateLabel() {
        var oldRight = label.Right;
        label.Text = "Hey here's some new text. It's pretty long so the control will have to resize";

        // Without this next line, the Right Anchor distance is not maintained.
        // label.Left -= (label.Right - oldRight);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(label.Anchor.HasFlag(AnchorStyles.Right) && label.Right == oldRight, "The label didn't stay anchored to the right");
    }
```

Obviously I can work around this by tracking the distance manually, as above.
I just wonder if there isn't some way this is “supposed” to work that I'm doing wrong.

The one observation I have to offer is this: it works if the label is not anchored to the bottom.

Do I need to call Suspend/Resume/PerformLayout on the Label? on the Form?
Are the docs wrong?
Am I being foolishly naïve or completely misunderstanding something?
Do I need some sort of intermediary Control for this to work and the docs assume I know this?

To address some possible complications that show up in similar questions (or that I dreamt up):

- `rightToLeft` is false,
- `Dock` is DockStyle.None,
- the label's `Parent` is the form itself, not an intermediary panel or other control.
- the `Margin` seems irrelevant
- Anchoring to the Top or Bottom seems irrelevant to Right not working.
- `System.Windows.Form.Button` works as expected. I haven't tested other controls.

Comment: Honestly I would make the label span across the entire bottom and the align the text right. It won't do what you want it to. You are trying to move the location of the label using anchors. I don't think I've ever seen that done (unless centering it horizontally/vertically). You could catch the resize event and do it manually. Like in the olden days.

Comment: If you add the Label to a container (e.g., a Panel) and Dock it to the Right of the Container, it will expand on the left (with `AutoSize = true`). You can anchor the Container Top/Right (or whatever else fits). The Container should also be set to Autosize.

Comment: You discovered that you don't like AutoSize = True.  It is the more "powerful" property to determine what is Right.  So set it to False, set TextAlign to TopRight, resize it to make it as big as it can reasonably be without overlapping anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `TableLayout`, it tends to obey the `Control` layout properties better. E.g:

```
public class MyForm : Form {

    Label label = new Label() { BackColor = Color.Blue, ForeColor = Color.White };

    public MyForm() {

        TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel() { BackColor = Color.Green };
        panel.ColumnCount = 1;
        panel.RowCount = 1;
        panel.Controls.Add(label, 0, 0);
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

        panel.Controls.Add(label);

        //this.label.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;// | AnchorStyles.Bottom; // ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        //this.label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.label.AutoSize = true;
        this.label.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        //this.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, 400);
        //this.label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 20);
        this.label.Text = "[Populated at Runtime]";
        //this.label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // ...
        //this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        //this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        //this.Controls.Add(this.label);
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        // ...

        Button btn = new Button { Text = "Change text" };
        btn.Click += delegate {
            PopulateLabel();
        };
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    // Sometime after Form Initialization, this is called
    void PopulateLabel() {
        var oldRight = label.Right;
        label.Text = "Hey here's some new text. It's pretty long so the control will have to resize";

        // Without this next line, the Right Anchor distance is not maintained.
        // label.Left -= (label.Right - oldRight);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(label.Anchor.HasFlag(AnchorStyles.Right) && label.Right == oldRight, "The label didn't stay anchored to the right");
    }

}
```